# Intuition about Toroidal Embeddings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

I have been trying to understand the very basics of toroidal embeddings, and the definitions on the face of them are not terribly daunting. I've been going with the "locally analytically looks like a torus inside a toric variety" mantra.

For the record, a toroidal embedding is an open set $U\subset X$ in a normal variety, such that for every $p\in X$, there is a toric variety $Y_p$ and a point $t$ inside $Y_p$ such that the completion of the local rings at $x$ and $t$ are isomorphic, and this isomorphism carries the ideal of $X-U$ to that of $Y_p-T$.

Obviously toric varieties are a a collection of examples. I have read that $\overline M_{g,n}$ has the structure of a toroidal embedding coming from $M_{g,n}$. I have a couple of questions:

1. I do not really understand the $\overline M_{g,n}$ example that I listed above, is there a good way to think about this?
2. Is there a nice non-toric example that people who understand this stuff really well keep in mind when thinking about these gadgets?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think that one of the most important features of a toroidal embedding is to keep track of the divisors $X \setminus U$. That seems more important than the isomorphism for every $p \in U$.

Comment: Well, for the particular application I have in mind, the existence of toric open charts seems fairly important too. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "keep track of the divisors"?

Comment: It would be great if there was an example of some "really non-convex" polyhedron, e.g. a triangulation of a torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$ corresponding to some explicit variety...